# Want to show only query string in url routing asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to rewrite the URL with query string. Here is an example

e.g

`www.test.com/user.aspx?Name=1234`

I want to rewrite like

`www.test.com/1234`

It is working fine with `www.test.com?Name=1234` to `www.test.com/test/1234`

I am doing it like:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute",
        "{Name}",
        "~/Webpages/Test/Demo.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("UserRoute", "{Name}", "~/user.aspx");

    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

To access the value, use `var v = Page.RouteData.Values["Name"];`

A user navigating to www.test.com/1234 will be handled by www.test.com/user.aspx and the number `1234` will be passed through and accessed using the code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, your problem is that you need to request a URL like www.test.com/1234 instead of www.test.com/test/1234.

This can be done using the route which you have mentioned in the global.asax file. But the issue here is that you have directly used a single dynamic parameter {Name} while defining your route. If you want to define any other route with a single parameter, then it will not work as explained below:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute","{Name}","~/Webpages/Test/Demo.aspx");
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute1","{Name1}","~/Webpages/Test/Demo1.aspx");
```

In the above case, the second route will be overriden by the first route declared.

That is the reason, it's better to give a static parameter in the route declaration.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute","test/{Name}","~/Webpages/Test/Demo.aspx");
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("StoreRoute1","test1/{Name1}","~/Webpages/Test/Demo1.aspx");
```

In the later case, the second route will not be overriden.

Now, if you only have to define a single route, then your code will work.

You can check my blog series on URL routing at below link. This link is of my resent post.

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-same.html

Thanks & Regards,
Munjal